# C# - Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' (setting value in a DropDownList)

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to set the selected value of a DropDownList from the codebehind. Here is the HTML for the DropDownList:

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$area" id="MainContent_area">
    <option value="1">Test area 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test area 2</option>
</select>
```

I can update the database just fine using this code to store the postback value into the object:

```
Area_Urn = int.Parse(area.SelectedValue)
```

However, when I try to then set the value back to the value that's stored in the database using this code:

```
area.SelectedValue = c.Area_Urn
```

Despite `c.Area_Urn` being an `int`, I get an error saying:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

I have tried `Int.Parse()` and `ToString()` (not sure why this would work, but I tried it out of desperation) but unfortunately I just cannot figure out what is causing this problem.

Comment: `area.SelectedValue = c.Area_Urn.ToString() `

Comment: This can catch you out of you come from a VB background, but C# doesn't do much in the way of implicit conversion. You have to explicitly `ToString` ints to concat them

Answer (score 3):

```
area.SelectedValue = c.Area_Urn.ToString()
```

That should do it

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this and it stayed underline with the same error, but I stupidly didn't actually try to build the code... (I guess Visual Studio just had a bit of lag whilst working out the errors)

Comment: Yes sometimes the intellisense takes a while to catch up!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign the `int` value to the `string` type. So you need to convert int to string. So try this

```
area.SelectedValue = c.Area_Urn.ToString()
```

or

```
area.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(c.Area_Urn);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this and it stayed underline with the same error, but I stupidly didn't actually try to build the code... (I guess Visual Studio just had a bit of lag whilst working out the errors)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is strange, normally i would expect the opposite:

> Cannot implicitly convert type  'int' to 'string'

However, since `SelectedValue` is a string and `c.Area_Urn` is an `int` that doesn't work.

```
area.SelectedValue = c.Area_Urn.ToString();  // now you assign a string to a string property
```